# ArgumentNullException for Integer

Tags: .net

In .NET, is it more appropriate to throw an argument null exception for an Integer if the value is Integer.MinValue or Integer = 0 (assuming that 0 is not a valid value)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Throwing an ArgumentNullException isn't appropriate unless the argument is actually **null**. Throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException instead (preferably with a message informing the user what values of int are actually acceptable).

> **ArgumentOutOfRangeException** is thrown when a method is invoked and at least one of the arguments passed to the method is not a null reference (**Nothing** in Visual Basic) and does not contain a valid value.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think if you are using an int, then it would be better to say InvalidArgumentException.

Alternatively, you could make your INTs nullable by declaring them as *int?* (especially if you expect null values for your int.)

Answer (score 0):

If the argument is not null, don't throw an `ArgumentNullException`. It would probably be more reasonable to throw an `ArgumentException`, [explained here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx)

**edit:** `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is probably even better, as suggested above by Avenger546.